# Send file FTP over SSL with custom port number

Tags: php, ssl, ssh, ftps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113310/warning-mysql-fetch-row-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource)

I have asked the question before but in a different manner. I am trying taking form data, compiling into a temporary CSV file and trying to send over to a client via FTP over SSL (this is the only route I am interested in hearing solutions for unless there is a workaround to doing this, I cannot make changes). I have tried the following:

1. ftp_connect - nothing happens, the
   page just times out
2. ftp_ssl_connect - nothing happens,
   the page just times out
3. curl library - same thing, given URL
   it also gives error.

I am given the following information:

- FTPS Server IP Address
- TCP Port (1234)
- Username
- Password
- Data Directory to dump file
- FTP Mode: Passive

very, very basic code (which I believe should initiate a connection at minimum):
Code:

```
<?php
$ftp_server = "00.000.00.000";  //masked for security
$ftp_port = "1234"; // masked but not 990
$ftp_user_name = "username";
$ftp_user_pass = "password";


// set up basic ssl connection
$conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server, $ftp_port, "20");

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

echo ftp_pwd($conn_id); // /
echo "hello";

// close the ssl connection
ftp_close($conn_id);

?>
```

When I run this over a SmartFTP client, everything works just fine. I just can't get it to work using PHP (which is a necessity). Has anybody had success doing this in the past? I would be very interested to hear your approach.

EDIT
I added the ftp_pasv() command after ftp_login as mentioned below but am still unable to connect. I am given the following errors:

> Warning: ftp_login() expects parameter
>   1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 12
>
> Warning: ftp_pasv() expects parameter
>   1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 14
>
> Warning: ftp_pwd() expects parameter 1
>   to be resource, boolean given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 16
>
> Warning: ftp_close() expects
>   parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on
>   line 20

Comment: Are you using a valid SSL cert or a self-signed SSL cert? Curl will try to validate the SSL cert against a cert authority. SmartFTP you can click past the SSL cert validation. PHP's `ftp_ssl_connect()` might also try to validate the SSL cert.

Comment: @Geek Num 88 - I am using a valid ssl Cert obtained through Go Daddy

Comment: When you use smartFTP, does ssl work on port 20? typically that's port 21.

Comment: @JM4 a few more ideas, `ftp_pasv()` needs to be called after `ftp_login()`. Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: @JM4 also just to be sure the *remote* server needs a valid SSL cert not your server

Comment: @Dan - the port number is irrelevant but fyi we are connecting to port 4433 in this case. @Geek Num 88 - I'll have to ask the client on the SSL cert on their end. I'll try using the ftp_pasv() command as well

Comment: Irrelevant? Do you mean you're not posting the 'real' one and have already take that into consideration? Otherwise it is definitely relevant: if i try to connect to my FTP server on port 21 when it's running on 2222, it ain't gonna work :p

Comment: @Dan - I do not post the real port number in the example code. The real port is 4433 as I said before. Connecting using PHP fails out. Connecting using SmartFTP works with the settings described above.

Comment: Ok ok - just makin' sure. I was afraid you meant "it's port 4433, but i'm putting 20 in my code because it doesn't matter", heh. It's the 'you sure its plugged in?' part of me...

Answer (score 0):

Is FTP enabled in your PHP installation? Use phpinfo(); to echo your installation info. There should be a section for ftp, with "FTP Support - enabled" in a table.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find out which secure FTP you are using,

1. SFTP : SSH FTP
2. FTPS : FTP over SSL

For FTPS to work, the openssl module must be statically linked (not installed as a dynamic extension).

SFTP requires PECL ssh2 extension.

Comment: @ZZ Coder - As the question states, I'm looking for 2 - FTPS - FTP over SSL. I'm not sure what 'statically linked' means in this terms of this question.

Comment: Check your php.ini, if you see something like "extension=openssl.so", it's dynamic. FTPS doesn't work with dynamic extensions. But this is probably not your problem. We get errors right away, not hanging.

Comment: @ZZ Coder - this extension doesn't exit on my system so I dont think it's the cause of the error

Comment: Check a similar line for FTP also. Both needs to be static. Another suggestion is to try CURL with a syntax like "ftps://host:port/path/file".