# Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

I am receiving the below message when I run this script:

Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /var/www/html/toolkit/routing.php on line 12

I have ran the query in the mysql console and it prints the correct row. Not sure why I cant get it to show up in php?

routing.php page:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
////error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
include("db/sbc_config.php");
include("db/mysql.class.php");
$db = new MySQL(true, DB_DATABASE_ROUTING, DB_SERVER, DB_USER , DB_PASS);
if ($db->Error()) $db->Kill();

        $searchroute = "SELECT * FROM destination_route as d WHERE d.destPrefix='2146811'";

        $result = mysql_fetch_row($searchroute);
    echo $result;

    ?>
```

sbc_config.php:

```
<?php
//database server
define('DB_SERVER', "10.10.1.146");

//database login name"
define('DB_USER', "user");

//database login password
define('DB_PASS', "pasword");

//database names
define('DB_DATABASE_ROUTING', "routing");

//smart to define your table names also
define('TABLE_DESTINATION_ROUTE', "destination_route");


?>
```

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D%20parameter%20resource%20mysql

Comment: There may be error connecting to database.In this case also you can get this error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_row` takes a cursor and returns the next row in that cursor. You're trying to give it a string. You're missing a step.

You'll have to execute that query first:

```
$cursor = mysql_query($searchroute); // for example
$result = mysql_fetch_row($cursor);
```

Comment: I am getting "Array" when I implement.. but no errors.

Comment: Because it returns an array. Output it with `print_r`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to execute the query before you can fetch results:

```
$searchroute = "SELECT *  ...";
$results = mysql_query($searchroute);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($results);
```

Comment: All of the above solutions come back with "Array" when I implement.. but no errors.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_row must be called after mysql_query, you can't pass the query into the fetch row
 - see [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$db = new MySQL(true, DB_DATABASE_ROUTING, DB_SERVER, DB_USER , DB_PASS);
```

is that supposedto be MySQLi? The mysql_*() functions do not have an OOP interface. You'd be mising mysqli and mysql calls, which is not supported. They're completely independent of each other internally, and a db handle or result statement from one is NOT useable in the other.